# Intel Documentation for MKL: Where do I get function lists for these libraries?

Tags: intel-mkl

I am writing an automake configure file, and I am having trouble discovering functions for the libary checks on these libraries:

```
mkl_core
mkl_gf_lp64
mkl_gnu_thread
```

There seems to be a wall of "marketing-level" documentation, but nothing specific. There must be some function list, somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

You may take a look at the MKL User Guide. Please check the Detailed Structure of the Intel® 64 Architecture Directories follow this link: `https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-linux-developer-guide-detailed-structure-of-the-intel-64-architecture-directories`
Regarding the list of supported functions: MKL contains > 2000 functions. You may refer to the including directory and to MKLDeveloper Reference Manual for C `https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-developer-reference-c` and for FORTRAN `https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-developer-reference-fortran`

Comment: FYI “over 2000 functions” isn’t really that many.  Just need one for automake to check that the library is installed.  It can be any function.

Comment: Tarick, I am a novice to this forum and I am not sure what do you mean by correct html?